# Prolog Combining Two Lists

Tags: list, prolog, append

I am new to prolog and would appreciate any help on the following question:

I need to write a program that accepts two lists and appends the second to first and displays this new list and its length. I know that prolog might have some built in functions to make this all easier...but I do not want to use those.

eg: `newlist([a,b,c],[d,e,f],L3,Le).` would return `L3=[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and `Le=6`

Here is what I have so far:

```
newlist([],List,List,0) 

newlist([Element|List1],List2,[Element|List3],L) :- newlist(List1,List2,List3, LT), L is LT + 1.
```

This does the appending correctly but I can only get the length of the first list instead of the combined list. Is there a way for me to add the second list's length to the first to get the combined list length?

Thanks, and sorry if this question is rather easy...I am new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to add the second list's length to the first to get the combined list length?

You should replace:

```
newlist([],List,List,0).
```

with:

```
newlist([],List,List,X):-length(List,X).
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do so, I get an existence error. Are you assuming that I already have length defined?

Comment: It is a built-in predicate in most prolog environments. However, if it is not, you can define it in a very similar way as what you did for `newlist`.

Comment: You could also use `newlist` in a weird way to turn it into a sort of `length`. However IMHO this wouldn't be very elegant.

Comment: But note that the new predicate needs to do more work as it needs to traverse the second list as well. Runtime is O(N+M) instead of O(N), where N is the length of the first list and M of the second.

Comment: @MikeHartl Sure. That's why the usual way to concatenate lists doesn't involve length computation. However this was what was asked for in the question. And if you need both concatenation and length computation, it is still more efficient than doing them separately.

Comment: @Aurélien: Of course. Just wanted to point it out to ilikecats ;-)