# Prolog - Merging 2 lists gives me a list of lists instead of a single list

Tags: list, prolog, append

I have tried many solutions and this is as close as I have come to the result I am expecting.

I want to combine 2 lists, but i am getting a list of lists rather than one list.

```
res1(Title,L3) :- findall(Genre,(book(Title,_,Genre,_)),L3).
res2(Author,L2) :- findall(Genre,(name(Author,Editor,_), house(Editor,_,Genre)),L2).
finalres(Title,Author,L) :- res1(Title,L3), res2(Author,L2), merged(L3, L2, L).

merged([],List,List).
merged([Element|List1],List2,[Element|List3]) :- merged(List1,List2,List3).
```

The merged code comes from [Prolog Combining Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018398/prolog-combining-two-lists).

When I attempt this by writing two lists in arguments, i get the proper result:

```
?- merged([g1,g2],[g3,g4],L).
L = [g1, g2, g3, g4].
```

However when I call it through my finalres, I get the following:

```
?- finalres("some title",a1,L).
L = [[g3, g4], [g1, g2]]
```

I would like to see `L = [g3, g4, g1, g2]`- the order does not bother me.
I also don't need to remove dupes from list (I'll deal with member later :) )

Is it because the second argument of merged (List2) is never separated? Am i misunderstanding how this append code works?

Using SWI-Prolog.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not just use `append/3`?

Comment: What are the third parameters of `book/4`? Atoms or lists?

Comment: If the calls to `findall/3` return lists of lists, then you need to "flatten" the result. Use the search function on the site.

Comment: @TomasBy yes the Genre is a list indeed. [g1, g2] for example. Ill go ahead and try append/3 and see about findall/flattening! Thanks for your time, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using the suggested answer in comments:

```
finalres(Title,Author,K) :- res1(Title,L3), 
                            res2(Author,L2), 
                            merged(L3, L2, L),
                            flatten(L, K).
```